# É possível utilizar Query String e Hash ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: php, html, string, hash

Estou desenvolvendo um site de uma página só usando as hash's html para rolar a página até o id especificado, porem surgiu a necessidade de utilizar também uma `query` string com `php`, só que agora sempre que tento usar os dois não funciona. A página não fica na parte que eu quero, volta sempre pro topo da página. Tem como usar os dois juntos e quando eu chamar a `query` a página continuar onde está?

Comment: Você tem um exemplo de URL que está usando? Talvez você não esteja colocando o hash no lugar certo.

Comment: Ta assim:
http://meusite.com.br/index.php#bloco03?id=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (em inglês), quando se usa um fragmento (expresso via hash - `#`) e uma *query string* (expressa via `?`) na mesma URL, o fragmento deve ser colocado **depois** da query string. Exemplo:

```
http://meusite.com.br/index.php?id=1#bloco03
```

Comment: Ah funcionou, era só isso mesmo.

Comment: @HermesNetto Disponha! Se achar que a resposta resolveu satisfatoriamente seu problema, você pode [marcá-la como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).